# Connecting to a heroku bash

Tags: bash, heroku

So i was letting a python script run overnight in heroku bash. When i checked in the morning, i had been disconnected from the bash. I ran `heroku run bash -a (my application name)` again, but when i checked my files they were all missing.

When i started heroku, it mentioned being ran on `run.4951`, but when i reconnected to the bash, it says `run.8786`

Is there a way i can reconnect to `run.4951`, or will i have to start over again?

Thanks,
Salmaan

Comment: To check if the process is still running try `heroku run ps -p 4951`.  [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/115968/ssh-session-drops-does-the-command-continue-executing) describes what happens to a process after an SSH timeout.

Comment: Ah ok. I did the command and it says `PID TTY          TIME CMD`. What does this mean? Timeout?

Comment: It means that `ps` could not find the PID. The process was killed after heroku disconnected.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there a way to make it so that it doesn't kill the process?